# SQL SELECT from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, relationship

```
ft_pupils
- id //Primary Key
- name
- start_date

ft_entries
- id
- pupil_id //Foreign Key 
- aol_id

ft_aol
- id
- title
```

For every entry in the ft_entries table I want to use a SELECT to select every entry in the ft_entries table but with the aol_id replaced with the title inside of ft_aol.

I have managed to get:

```
SELECT name, aol_id FROM ft_pupils, ft_entries WHERE pupil_id = ft_pupils.id
```

to work fine.

I want the WHERE to be WHERE pupil_id = ft_pupils.id

I am so confused right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this to get what you want by join 3 table.

```
SELECT Name,title FROM ft_entries 
INNER JOIN ft_pupils ON pupil_id = ft_pupils.id
LEFT JOIN ft_aol ON ft_aol.id = aol_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This will show you how to get the data you're looking for and display all the ids. You can remove the ids if you don't care to see them:

```
SELECT a.id,
       b.pupil_id,
       c.id,
       a.NAME,
       a.start_date,
       c.title
FROM   ft_pupils a
       JOIN ft_entries b ON a.id = b.pupil_id
       JOIN ft_aol c ON c.id = b.aol_id
```